# How to commit-push ionic 3 blank to my GitHub repository?

Tags: github, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm starting with ***Ionic 3***, but i have a problem to upload (commit, push) changes from my local machine to my github repository.
I follow those instructions:

**step 1:**

[image]

**step 2:**

[image]

**step 3:**

[image]

**step 4:**

[image]

**I got the message "nothing to commit ..."**

**step 5:**

As you can see, there are files inside the project (sorry by the arrows):

[image]

**step 6:** .gitignored file

[image]

What is wrong?
I need upload to my repo: https://github.com/myAccount/ionic_test_1.git

Can anybody help me?

Comment: what do you see when you do `git status` ??

Comment: And what's in your .gitignore file

Comment: this is the result after `git status`-->  `On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`. it's like nothing inside the folder project.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby - about the gitignored, i update my question with the image, can you help me understand what is wrong?, why i can upload to my github repository?

Comment: You didn't mention if/how you created your local repository. (I'd git clone it and run the ionic start ... command in there afterwards.) Check `git status --ignored` to see if files have been ignored by accident and `git remote -v` to see what repository you are actually using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First Delete your .git(hidden folder) folder inside your project directory.
then,
1)git init
2)git remote add origin YOUR_GITPROJECT_URL
3)git add . ->dot after add then space then dot
4)git commit -m "COMMIT_MESSAGE"
4)git push -u origin master

Comment: i got it, now i can upload all my project. Thanks